# Are there crowd-sourced websites for travel bucket lists?

Tags: online-resources, planning, japan

I'm in the early stages of planning a three week trip to Japan, and I'm still working out where to go. There's a couple of things on my "to do" list, but I want to find out if there's any activities or attractions that I'd be kicking myself for not seeing if this were my last trip to Japan.

I've done a bit of googling for individuals' bucket lists, but it can be frustrating when the same item gets repeated on multiple lists, such as the [Kanamara Matsuri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanamara_Matsuri) being listed on http://thetravellingdork.com/2012/04/bucket-list-20-things-to-do-when-i-get-to-japan/ and http://www.blakeinjapan.com/japan-bucket-list/

Are there any good web 2.0 style sites, where there is information contributed by several people, without the same attractions being listed multiple times?

Ideally, when appropriate the information would be organized by type of activity and not merely by an individual attraction, so you'd be able to see "See a kabuki play" as an item, rather than having all the different theatres clutter up the list.

Comment: I assume that japanese sites are out of the question? Are you looking for "any stuff / all over japan" or can it be specific sites for specific types of events?

Comment: @uncovery 1) it depends how easy it is to feed the Japanese text into Google Translate, I guess. 2) "Any stuff / all over Japan" is preferred, but I'll appreciate information on specific sites for specific types of events anyway.

Comment: By "Web 2.0" do you mean pretentious, overhyped and pointless?

Comment: @DJClayworth you forgot to mention "and a massive time sink"!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you could try is [Schemer](https://www.schemer.com/find/Japan). This is a Google service for sharing and discovering things to do.

Google shut down Schemer on February 7, 2014.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that TripAdvisor has a convenient map mode which could be used to find the most popular destinations in a given area, aka the "bucket list" of any given city. For example, [here are their top picks](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attractions-g154943-Activities-Vancouver_British_Columbia.html#MAPVIEW) for Vancouver:

[image]

Google Maps has the potential to be just as useful if they let you search for the most reviewed locations in a given area, but unfortunately this feature is not available yet, although you can find a list-based form on [Top-rated.online](https://www.top-rated.online/).